# Android List formatting

Tags: android, list, formatting

I would to know if it possible to create this kind of list for Android: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-formatting.html
I didn't find any example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd have to implement a custom ListView.